# How to get a data API from another function in python django

Tags: python, django

I am doing an project that pulling user API from github and I successfully done that but I'm working on how to show that data on a chart. I'm using Chart.js

Here is my `views.py`:

```
def user(req, username):
    username = str.lower(username)

    # Get User Repo Info
    with urlopen(f'https://api.github.com/users/{username}/repos') as response:
        source = response.read()
    sorted_by_stars = json.loads(source)

    def sort_user_repo_by_stars(sorted_by_stars):
        return sorted_by_stars['stargazers_count']

    sorted_by_stars.sort(key=sort_user_repo_by_stars, reverse=True)



    context = {
        'username': username,
        'sorted_by_stars': sorted_by_stars[:8],
    }
    return render(req, 'user.html', context)


class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        labels = ["Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
        default_items = [ DATA ]
        data = {
            "labels": labels,
            "default": default_items,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

I want to get data that I pulled from github which is `sorted_by_stars = json.loads(source)` and it put in ChartData. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can put that part of code in a method and use it any function. For example:

```
def get_stars(username):
    with urlopen(f'https://api.github.com/users/{username}/repos') as response:
        source = response.read()
    return json.loads(source)

def user(req, username):
    username = str.lower(username)
    sorted_by_stars=get_stars(username)
    ...

class ChartData(APIView):
    ...

    def get(self, request, username=None, format=None):
        labels = ["Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
        stars = get_stars(username)  # or use request.user.username if the use is authenticated with github username
        # rest of the code
```

You can also store this information in [**`request.session`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/) and use it different views. For example:

```
def user(req, username):
    username = str.lower(username)
    sorted_by_stars=get_stars(username)
    req.session['stars']=sorted_by_stars
    # rest of the code

class ChartData(APIView):
        ...
        def get(self, request, format=None):
           stars = request.session.get('stars', None)
           # rest of the code
```